# Adding LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry excludes Dialect methods

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, hql, spatial

I'm using NHibernate and NHibernate.Spatial. The latter is defined in the configuration as a dialect with this value:

```
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Spatial.Dialect.MsSql2012GeometryDialect, NHibernate.Spatial.MsSql</property>
```

When I build the *SessionFactory* and evaluate it, it shows 189 named methods (see Settings.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry.registeredMethods).

Without the dialect the number is 147. The difference resolves to typical spatial functions like *Within, Distance, Area* etc.

I needed support for string concatenation so I created a custom *HQL generator* like this:

```
public class ConcatHqlGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
    public ConcatHqlGenerator() : base()
    {
        SupportedMethods = new[]
        {
            ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition(() => string.Concat(null, null)),
            ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition(() => string.Concat(null, null, null)),
            ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition(() => string.Concat(null, null, null, null))
        };
    }
    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, Expression targetObject, ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments,
        HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        return treeBuilder.Concat(new[]
        {
            visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(), visitor.Visit(arguments[1]).AsExpression()
        });
    }
}

public class LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry() : base()
    {
        this.Merge(new ConcatHqlGenerator());
    }
}
```

Which i registered prior to building the *session factory* like this:

```
configuration.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry, typeof(LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry).AssemblyQualifiedName);
```

However, when I do this the spatial methods (introduced by the dialect) are not loaded and I get errors when using Linq functions like *Within* etc. Evaluating the settings also show that the registered method count is now 150, which is the default 147 and the additonal custom three.

Has anyone used NHibernate.Spatial and also created custom HQL generators in combination and gotten this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Inherit NHibernate.Spatial.Linq.Functions.SpatialLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry rather than NHibernate.Linq.Functions.DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry